# Select time between range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `users` with column `offsetUTC`, type `text`. It contains data like `+01:30` or `-02:00`. And I want select users whose time now is between '23:55:00' and '00:05:00'.

This script doesn't work properly and I don't know why.

```
select * from "Users"
where (timezone('utc', now()) + "offsetUTC"::interval)::time 
between '23:55:00'::time and '00:05:00'::time;
```

Also tried avoiding `between` but no result.

```
select * from "Users"
where (timezone('utc', now()) + "offsetUTC"::interval)::time >= '23:55:00'::time 
and (timezone('utc', now()) + "offsetUTC"::interval)::time < '00:05:00'::time;
```

`select (timezone('utc', now()) + "offsetUTC"::interval)::time from "Users";` returns `00:01:00`

UPD: The problem appears only when I'm querying between `23` and `00`.

Comment: explain what  "This script doesn't work properly " means . also provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana I add edit and explain when this problem appears

Comment: You are trying to make a timestamp comparison with time values. In other words you are crossing midnight without adding a date component to make that clear.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for explanation! But I still don't know how to do it properly

Comment: I don't have time for a complete solution, but something like: `select current_date + '23:55:00'::time; , select (current_date + interval '1 day') + '00:05:00'::time;` for the comparison timestamps. You will probably need a `CASE` statement to test whether the second value is less then the first, indicating crossing midnight. There are already SO answers for this, so try searching.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks a lot for help!